# Laravel 8: how to retrieve data of a one to one relationship in existing database?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, one-to-one

I am having some problems retrieving data in a one-to-one relationship.
I have this existing Table and I want to retrieve the data from rfp_details.
here is my code

```
//rfpmain model
protected $table = 'accounting.request_for_payment';
public function rfpDetail(){
    return $this->hasOne(RfpDetail::class);
}


//rfp detail model
protected $table = 'accounting.rfp_details';
public function rfpMain(){
    return $this->belongsTo(RfpMain::class);
}

//rfp controller
public function show($id)
{
    $rfpMain = RfpMain::findOrFail($id);
    $rd = $rfpMain->rfpDetails;
    dd($rd);
}
```

below is the structure of my existing database

[image]

Comment: i tried to make a model for my existing db. my problem is when I make a relationship between those two. i cant retrieve the rfp_details. i don't know what did I do wrong. or it is not allowed to make an eloquent to existing database?

Comment: Actually, the problem is `typo` when you access a relationship. `rfpDetail` is your relationship name but you have used `rfpDetails` where `s` is not needed.

Comment: yes thank you for noticing. i have new problem it returns a blank {}.
i don't know if is because of my models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define the foreign key in your relationship because if you can't define it then it will take the default value which is different in your case.

You need to replace from

```
public function rfpDetail(){
    return $this->hasOne(RfpDetail::class);
}
```

To

```
public function rfpDetail(){
    return $this->hasOne(RfpDetail::class,'rfpid');
}
```

Comment: sir, thank you how about my retrieve in controller is it right?

Comment: Yes, it is right. If my answer is helpful for you then please upvote me and approved the answer that will appreciate my work.

Comment: it doesn't work for me i really want to upvote this

Comment: try to replace from ` $rd = $rfpMain->rfpDetails; ` to  ` $rd = $rfpMain->rfpDetails(); `

Comment: BadMethodCallException sir. thank you for helping me

Comment: i dont know if it is my rfp_detail model is the problem

Comment: Got is you need to remove the s from the `$rd = $rfpMain->rfpDetails()` it should be `$rd = $rfpMain->rfpDetail();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237779/discussion-between-paul-iverson-cortez-and-kudosintech).

Comment: let us continue this in chat please

Comment: Im I correct that the naming convention is xxxx_id with `_id` for hasOne() to find the keys automatically. Adding `'rfpid'` will work as it specifies the name of your foreign key. As for `rfp_main`, it already has a standard `id` as its local_key.